# how can I make Multiselect work using jquery when having an ajax call and dynamic form generation

Tags: jquery

If someone can help me with this jquery multiselect. I have been generating a form with 
 multiselect option dynamically. My options are generated dynamically and I am having an AJax call for the same. Everytime the form is created a button is created with text "None selected" on it. When I click on the button nothing happens. 
If anyone can help me with it.

Comment: No one can help you with this sort of thing without seeing the code.

Comment: you need to show code you have tried. As per my understanding select2 may help you. but please put some code here.

Comment: Can you please add the minimum required HTML CSS JS code, so your issue can be figured out. You can create it directly in StackOverflow or you can use jsFiddle or CodePen to create the demo and share the link.